# Get Reference to ILogger in Azure Function Startup.cs

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In an Azure Function project is there a way to get a reference to ILogger inside the Configure() method of Startup.cs?

(I need to log some initialization steps that happen during the configuration hook)

```
public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
       //get reference to ILogger Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide more context so that so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `LoggerFactory` to create an Instance of `Ilogger` in your startup. Here's an working example for you.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                         .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                         .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                         .Build();

            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            ConfigureServices(builder);

        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            _loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            var logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");
            logger.LogInformation("Got Here in Startup");

            //Do something with builder
        }
    }
```

Comment: When this runs in Azure, where does it log to? I can't find it in App Insights. Can you share a host.json config to enable this?

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work?  I do not see the messages that get logged by this method anywhere, though I do see the messages sent to the ILogger that I get in the Run method.

Comment: Still a mystery for me too!